# The event changes <select> when choosing options

Tags: javascript, php

```
<select class="form-control form-control-alternative" id="sophut" name="sophut" >
    <option value="30">30 phút (100đ/1)</option>
    <option value="60">60 phút (100đ/1)</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$('#amount').keyup(function()
{
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    var service = <?=$rate_mat_auto;?>;
    var time = document.getElementById("sophut").value;

    var ck = <?=$my_ck;?>;
    var ketquaz = service * amount * time;
    var ketqua = ketquaz - ketquaz * ck / 100;
    $('#ketqua').html(ketqua.toString().replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,'$1,'));
    $('#soluong').html(amount.toString().replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,'$1,'));
    $('#sophut').change(function() { // on change
        $('#amount').keyup(); // trigger this
    });
```

How do I change "ketqua" when I change "sophut"?

I tried adding event onchange = "name?" go to  but I don't know "name?" What to fill out

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your event only works in conjunction with the keyup event.
Try to separate the two events listeners.